# Optimization of a step sequence

Tags: c, switch-statement

Currently we are developing a client/server application. In the client code we use a step sequence, performed by a switch/case. The code is working fine, but for me it's seems not quite right.
So here's the code.

```
while(true)
{
   switch(sub_step_1){
       case 1:  /* Step 1: */
                ...
                sub_step_1++;
                break;

       case 2:  /* Step 2: */
                ...
                sub_step_1++;
                break;

       case 3:  /* Step 3: */
                ...
                sub_step_1++;
                break;

       case 4: /* Step 4: */ 
                ...
                sub_step_1=0;
                break;

       default:
                return 0;
   }
}
```

The step sequence is execute inside a function, and at the end it just returns to the main. Since everything works fine, I just wanted to ask if there is a possible way to optimize this sequence, espacially for debugging.

Comment: The cases seem identical to me. So it would be obvious to elliminate them.

Comment: step 4 is different, also I guess those `...` mean there's something else in there

Comment: Right. And we don't know what's behind `...`.

Comment: The key is what `...` is doing in each case.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I assumed they wouldn't have been so naive to not notice they were repeating code and didn't use fall-through

Comment: This whole thing smells of the [loop-switch sequence antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence) to me. Looks like this whole thing could just be `for(;;) { /*step1*/ /*step2*/ /*step3*/ /*step4*/ } return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that struck me as wrong is not so important, but your comment.
/* Step 3: */
is not step 3. it is actually step 1.
You dont go from switch case 1 to switch case 2 and so on because theres a break statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the sub_step_1 counter, then breaks, cases and switch, so your function becomes like this:

```
   /* Step 1: */
   ...
   /* Step 2: */
   ...
   /* Step 3: */
   ...
   /* Step 4: */
   ...
   return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a sequence of function ?

```
step1();
step2();
step3();
step4();
```

Or simply sequential code if you don't want to pass the context.